# How to Integrate React Components to a legacy app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created the following code in order to integrate React to a legacy old HTML/JS App gradually:

```
const components = [{
    element: <MainMenu/>,
    id: 'main-menu'
}, {
    element: <EventShop/>,
    id: 'event-shop',
}, {
    element: <Card/>,
    id: 'card',
}];

if (!isDev()) {
    components.forEach((component) => {
        const domElement= document.getElementById(component.id);
        if (domElement) {
            ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode>{component.element}</React.StrictMode>,
                domElement
            );
        } else {
            console.warn(`cannot find : ${component.id}`);
        }
    });
} else {
    ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
```

It works really well, but now I want to pass props/children from the legacy HTML to my react component.
I was thinking to use the `data-*` HTML attribute to pass props and access them from my JS, but what about children? e.g `<Card>{children}</Card>` - how I can access them from the DOM and use them in my react app?

then I was thinking.. am I re-inventing the wheel or there is a better way to integrate React into an existing HTML/JS project which is not react-based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your question is not exactly clear, but you could use `React.createElement` instead of JSX. Here's a snippet with `React.createElement` that copies DOM elements from the DOM to a `<Card />` element. (You could move them, if after copying you'd remove the original from the DOM.)

```js
const isDev = () => {
  return false
}

const MainMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div>Main menu</div>
  )
}

const EventShop = () => {
  return (
    <div>Event shop</div>
  )
}

const CardChild = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={ props.className }
    >
      Card child of { props.children }:<br />
      {
        JSON.stringify(props)
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const cardChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.card-child')

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Card:<br />
      {
        Array.prototype.map.call(cardChildren, function(item) {
          const tag = item.nodeName
          const classList = [...item.classList]
          const dataProps = item.getAttribute("data-props")
          return (
            <div>
              {
                React.createElement(
                  CardChild,
                  {
                    props: {
                      tag: item.nodeName,
                      dataProps: item.getAttribute("data-props"),
                    },
                    className: classList.join(" "),
                  },
                  item.textContent
                )
              }
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const components = [{
  element: <MainMenu/>,
  id: 'main-menu'
}, {
  element: <EventShop/>,
  id: 'event-shop',
}, {
  element: <Card/>,
  id: 'card',
}];

if (!isDev()) {
  components.forEach((component) => {
    const domElement= document.getElementById(component.id);
    if (domElement) {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
        {
          component.element
        }
        </React.StrictMode>,
        domElement
      );
    } else {
      console.warn(`cannot find : ${component.id}`);
    }
  });
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
```

```css
#card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card-child {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-menu"></div>

<div id="event-shop"></div>

<div id="card"></div>

<div class="card-child" data-props="a">i1</div>
<div class="card-child" data-props="b">i2</div>
<div class="card-child" data-props="c">i3</div>
```